# Customize size of Camera Preview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera-intent

I am launching the camera but it opens the camera in full size/ default preview size. Can I reduce the size of camera preview so that I can have the camera preview like a rectangle window? If so, how can I do that. If it is not possible to reduce the default camera view size, how can I crop the image from the captured image.

```
            protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, 
            [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
                imageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

             // using the cropped image bitmap for some other functionality           
            }
            private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
```

Basically, my requirement is to capture only some part of data in a sheet from the camera. I am not able to use surface view to reduce the size of the preview window as I don't think there is a possibility to click and capture image from Surface view.

Comment: try textureview with the new camerax api

Comment: Note that the bitmap that you read from `data.Extras.Get("data")` is not intended to be displayed on the full screen or saved in file. Its purpose is to deliver a small thumbnail.